# Expected end of input but got keyword ORDER in Bigquery Sandbox?

Tags: sql, syntax-error, sandbox

When I execute

```
SELECT 
purchase_price 
FROM 
`my-project-a-392201.customer_data2.customer_purchase` LIMIT 1000
ORDER BY
purchase_price DESC
```

I get

> Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword ORDER at [5:1]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try a different, less absurd table name, and yours is not an `standard sql` question, you may want to Tag your RDBMS, like `MariaDB` or `Oracle` or whatever you use

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax has Limit following Order By

```
SELECT purchase_price 
FROM my-project-a-392201.customer_data2.customer_purchase 
ORDER BY purchase_price DESC
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to help!